# A first chance exception of type "System.ArgumentException" occured in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, ftp, stream

```
  try
        {
            FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp path");
            req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
            using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(resp.WelcomeMessage);
            }
            FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            Stream rs = res.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader read1 = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());// prob A
            Console.WriteLine(read1.ReadToEnd());
            Console.WriteLine("Directory is compleate,status(0)",
            res.StatusDescription);
            read1.Close();
            rs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e1.Message);
        }
```

I am trying to access ftp server via C#.

However, the code errors with an exception:
`A first chance exception of type "System.ArgumentException" occured in mscorlib.dll. Stream was not readable.`

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First problem - you're calling `GetResponseStream()` twice - why? Next: show the whole stack trace, not just the message. We don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: You have already gotten the response with using(var resp = ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all `IDisposable` resources within `using(...) {...}`. That technics prevents
resource leaking/closed resources invoking:

```
try {
  FtpWebRequest req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp path");
  req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;

  // Response: we're going to work wuth respose within "using" block only
  using (FtpWebResponse resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()) {
    Console.WriteLine(resp.WelcomeMessage);

    // Reader: once again reader's opened once and called within using only
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())) {
      Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
      Console.WriteLine("Directory is complete, status(0)", resp.StatusDescription);
    }
  }
catch (Exception ex) { // <- Bad idea to catch all possible exceptions without "throw;"
  Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Sir, Can you please explain why above mentioned exception was occuring? was it because i was using FtpWebtResponse object twice or anything else?

Comment: @biz00ka: It's a very possible reason: You've opened Response in using() and .Net closed it on this block leaving (so it's disposed).  Next you try to get Response again (which is disposed). Since response is disposed you can't obtain a Stream to read

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; The state of the `FtpWebResponse` object is disposed, therefore you cannot read the response stream. The stream is closed.

Disassembly of FtpWebResponse:

```
public override void Close()
        {
            if (Logging.On)
            {
                Logging.Enter(Logging.Web, this, "Close", "");
            }
            if (this.HttpProxyMode)
            {
                this.m_HttpWebResponse.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Stream responseStream = this.m_ResponseStream;
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    responseStream.Close();
                }
            }
            if (Logging.On)
            {
                Logging.Exit(Logging.Web, this, "Close", "");
            }
        }
```

---

The reason you get the exception, is that you are reading the response:

```
using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine(resp.WelcomeMessage);
}
```

and on the next line, you try to read the response again, into another variable: `res`

```
FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream rs = res.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader read1 = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());// prob A
```

In that section, you also do a call to the `res.GetResponseStream()` twice, but that does not matter in terms of the error occuring. The error will occur even if you change it to:

```
FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Stream rs = res.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader read1 = new StreamReader(rs);// prob A
```

Or:

```
FtpWebResponse res = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
StreamReader read1 = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream());// prob A
```

The reason that the error occurs, is the state of the `FtpWebResponse` object, which is disposed; and has the `StatusCode = ClosingData`. When I try to read the stream in that state, I get the error you are experiencing. In the using block before, the `StatusCode = OpeningData`.

However, if you just change a couple of lines to:

```
using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine(resp.WelcomeMessage);
    Stream rs = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader read1 = new StreamReader(rs);// prob A
    Console.WriteLine(read1.ReadToEnd());
    Console.WriteLine("Directory is compleate,status(0)", res.StatusDescription);
}
```

When entering this using scope, the `StatusCode = OpeningData`, and stream is available and readable. When exiting the scope, the `StatusCode = ClosingData`, and stream will not be readable.

Hope this make some sense, and correct me if I'm wrong. :-)

With these small changes your code will run as expected. However you should look into the pattern @DmitryBychenko proposes. That way you will have access to the resources within the scope that they're needed, and disposed afterwards.

Comment: :Thank you for your time and effort to explain the problem.Really appreciate it. :)